# Weird notation for 2-variable Taylor polynomial?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I found a tool to compute taylor polynomials for 2-variable functions. In order to test the programm, I tried to find the first order Taylor polynomial of $f(x,y)=x^2+y^2$ in $(0,2)$.

The Taylor polynomial is correct, but I don't understand the formula:

[image]

Does $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ mean $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\big |_{x=0}$?

I am confused!

Comment: Almost. See the $f$ on the right, after the parentheses close. The notation is assumed to distribute the $f$ to both summands inside the parentheses and the concatenation of the symbol $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ and $f(x_0,y_0)$ is supposed to mean taking the partial derivative of $f$ and then evaluating it at $(x_0,y_0)$, not at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It only means the *differential operator* of partial differentiation w.r.t. $x$. One major advantage of this condensed  notation  is that for Taylor's formula at higher orders, it behaves like  the binomial formula.

*Example*: 
The general Taylor's formula at order $2$ in two variables is written as
\begin{align}f(x,y)&=f(x_0,y_0) +\frac1{1!}\Bigl((x-x_0)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+(y-y_0)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Bigr)\cdot f(x_0,y_0)\\r &+\frac1{2!}\Bigl((x-x_0)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+(y-y_0)\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\Bigr)^{\!2}\!\cdot f(x_0,y_0)+ o\bigl(\|(x-x_0,y-y_0)\|^2\bigr), 
\end{align}
which means precisely that

\begin{alignat}{2}f(x,y)&=&&f(x_0,y_0)+\frac1{1!}\Bigl((x-x_0)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)+(y-y_0)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)\Bigr)\cr &&&+\frac1{2!}\biggl((x-x_0)^2\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}(x_0,y_0)+2(x-x_0)(y-y_0)\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x\,\partial y}(x_0,y_0)+(y-y_0)^2\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(x_0,y_0)\biggr)+ o\bigl(\|(x-x_0,y-y_0)\|^2\bigr). 
\end{alignat}

Comment: But what about the third order if $T_n(x,y)=\sum \limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}\left((x-x_0)\frac{\partial}{\partial x}+(y-y_0)\frac{\partial }{\partial y}\right)^nf(x_0,y_0)$? I know that $(a+b)^3=a^3 + 3 a^2 b + 3 a b^2 + b^3$...

Comment: It begins explicitly with $$(x-x_0)^3\dfrac{\partial^3f}{\partial x^3}(x_0, y_0)+3(x-x_0)^2(y-y_0)\dfrac{\partial^3f}{\partial x^2\partial y}(x_0, y_0)+\dotsm $$In other words, the orders of differentiation w.r.t. each variable behave as symbolic exponents.

Comment: How do you know it's $\frac{\partial ^3}{\partial x^2 \partial y}$? Conversely, why isn't it $\frac{\partial ^3}{\partial y \partial x^2}$?

Comment: For a $C^2$ function, the order of variable while differentiating has no importance by Schwarz' theorem ,  and the binomial coefficients are symmetric. I know it is $\frac{\partial ^3}{\partial x^2 \partial y}$ because the monomial which goes with this partial derivative is $(x-x_0)^2(y-y_0)$.

Comment: Would $(y-y_0)(x-x_0)^2$ result in $\frac{\partial ^3}{\partial y \partial x^2}$...?!

Comment: Yes, why not? Except, usually  one fixes an order on the variables, and it is not changed in the middle of a formula, if only for readability reasons.

Comment: Ok, I guess I understand

Comment: Ok, so I tried computing $f(x,y)=\sin(x)\sin(y)$ using this formula and found $T_3(x,y)=-\frac{1}{12}\sqrt{2}x(16x^2+48y^2-24\pi+3\pi^2)$ is that correct?

Comment: You applied Taylor's formula near which point?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot; at $(0,\pi /4)$.

Comment: I cannot check your result at the moment, but for this case, why don't you multiply the expansion of $\sin x$ alone (near $0$) by the expansion of $\sin y$ near $\frac\pi 4$ (a polynomial in $y-\frac\pi 4$ alone), and truncate  at (total) degree $3$?

Comment: Sounds like a shortcut, sadly, I'm not sure what you mean...

Comment: You can check comparing the result of both ways.

Answer (score 0):

That answer is correct, but if the point is $(2,0)$ rather than $(0,2)$. In fact, note that\begin{align}x^2+y^2&=\bigl((x-2)+2\bigr)^2+y^2\\&=(x-2)^2+4(x-2)+4+y^2\end{align}And the Taylor polynomial that you're after is what you get after deleting those terms with degree greater than $1$; you will get $4(x-2)+4=4x-4$ indeed.

And here $\frac\partial{\partial x}$ is $\left.\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\right|_{x=x_0}$.